# How many numbers are there upto N which have digits 2,3,5 and divisible by 2,3,5?

Tags: algorithm, prime-factoring, number-theory

I have a set of digits {d1,d2,d3......dn} where , 1<=di<=9.  1<=n<=9

Now I wish to find out how many numbers are there <=N which have all these digits in them , in any order , and all those numbers are also divisible by these digits .

The way I think , is just to iterate from first number with length n to **N** and check , but is there more efficient solution ?

Example :

D = {2,3,5} and N = 10^10

How many numbers are there which have all these digits in them and are also multiple of 2,3 and 5.

Comment: At least comment and tell what's wrong before downvoting without any reason?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the downvote button has a tooltip "This question does not show any research effort...". That may apply here -- if you include evidence of what you've tried and where you got stuck, you may get upvotes and more helpful answers. If you've really no idea where to start beyond "try every number up to 10^10", perhaps you're attempting questions that are currently too difficult for you and you should be focusing your learning efforts for now on simpler questions. That's not meant to be an insult, but rather just something to consider as you're trying to improve.

Comment: 22350 contains 2,3 and 5 as digits. And it is divisible by 2,3 and 5. "A number containing those digits to be divisible by 2 it has to end with 2, but for it to be divisible by 5 it has to end with 5" ???

Comment: I interpreted "which have all these digits in them , in any order" to mean contains only those digits. I see now that you meant that it must contain at least one of each of the digits in D. I'll delete my comment because it was based on this wrong assumption.

Comment: You say that "22350" is a solution, but it's not generated by the answer you accepted (which only generates solutions containing the digits of D).

Comment: What you mean is the numbers that have each of  those digits *at least once*, and divide evenly by all of them, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure from your question if you want numbers that are only divisible by 2, 3 and 5, or if you will accept numbers divisible by some other number as long as 2, 3 and 5 are among the divisors. Assuming the first alternative:

First, compute the hamming numbers (numbers divisible by 2, 3 and 5); there are only a few thousand of them under 10^10, and they are easy to compute. Second, examine each one to determine if it uses digits other than 2, 3 or 5.

The hamming numbers can be computed by induction. Start with 1, which is a hamming number. Then, if *x* is a hamming number, so are 2 *x*, 3 *x* and 5 *x*.

If you need help reducing this to code, ask.

**EDIT**: Based on the comment below, you want the second alternative ("have to check all multiples of 2"). Consider then the case for 2, 3 and 5. First generate all 1-digit numbers containing 2, 3 or 5, which is trivial. Then generate all 2-digit numbers containing 2, 3 or 5: 22, 23, 25, 32, 33, 35, 52, 53, 55. And so on for each *n*-digit number up to your limit. Finally, test each for divisibility; for the list above, 23 and 53 would be excluded as not being divisible by 2, 3 or 5.

In either case, the trick is to generate a small set of numbers that meets one of the criteria, then check the other criteria.

Comment: Thank you . But if D = {2} then , it would be a problem as I would have to check all multiples of 2 in this manner.

Comment: Unrelated, but I think your definitions of Hamming Numbers is incorrect.  Hamming numbers are divisible by 2, 3, **and/or** 5 ... but not necessarily 2, 3, **and** 5.  https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hamming_numbers

Answer (score 1):

If you're just going to iterate, then you should know that any number that is divisible by a set of numbers will also be divisible by the least common multiple (I think that's the right term) of those numbers.

So in your case, if a number is divisible by 2 and 3 and 5, then it is also divisible by 30.

That should speed up your iteration plan.

Comment: So, this way I can just look for multiples of 30 and see if they contain 2,3 and 5 as their digits . But , still it's complexity is N*log(N)/30 . It will just reduce time by the factor lcm(d1,d2,d3....dn). Are there any faster way ?BTW,  Thanks for this approach .